# Cookie always ask for input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem. The JavaScript always displays a box to ask for the input every time I reload the page. It supposes to ask only once and then when I reload the page, it should display "Welcome again: your_input_here". I did try it with the VS Code using Live Server, and it worked. However, when I go to the folder which contains the files and click on the index.html file. It displayed a box ask for input, I did type the input in and click the submit button, then when I reload the page, the box displayed one more time and asks for the input without saving my last input. Can someone help me? Thank you

```js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
  }
  
  function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
      }
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
      }
    }
    return "";
  }
  
  function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
      alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
      user = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
      if (user != "" && user != null) {
        setCookie("username", user, 365);
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-width=1">
        <script src="./cookie.js"></script>  
        <title>A14</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="checkCookie()">
      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cookies are bound a domain, and a filesystem path in the address bar of your browser is not a domain. You have to use liveserver to test this feature

Comment: Cookies not working when browsing using the file:/// protocol, depending on the browser.